# SMTP tunnel forwarding

Tags: amazon-ec2, smtp, amazon-web-services, tunnel, amazon-ses

I will like to know if there is any SMTP tunnel that you can setup to run on localhost:25 and have it forward mails to Amazon SES (TLS/SMTPS) using a username and password that you specify in the SMTP tunnel settings.

My problem is that I have an old program that I want to move over to Amazon EC2 and I want it to use Amazon SES as SMTP. But it only allows me to change the SMTPServerName setting. The username and password are empty and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

This user documentation will help you.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SMTP.MTAs.html

Comment: I cannot find any information on how to get the tunnel software to override the username and password that the client is sending.

Comment: Which language and library/plugin are you using ?

Comment: I tried using the http://www.stunnel.org from the amazon documentation that you linked. Setting it up as a "smtp-tls-wrapper". Accepting all mails from local port 25 and then forward it to the Amazon SMTP. But I couldn't find any configuration where I can override the incoming username and password and forward it to amazon SMTP.

For example the old-program sends a mail to localhost:25 with username and password as empty. I want the tunnel to forward the mail to Amazon using SES SMTP Credentials that I got from Amazon.

Comment: stunnel will only help you to connect to SES endpoint (email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com). Configuring SMTP username/password to forward mails should be part of your old program (SMTP client/software package/email server). If you can put some light on your old program, may be i can help.